# How to call parameter in meta title in route vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i have problem when im trying to call parameter in meta title route,

i already tried like this but still not working

```
{
    path: '/test/blog/:slug',
    name: 'Surah',
    component: Surah,
    meta: { title: 'My Blog - 'this.$route.params.slug}
  }
```

can you help me to solve this ? i need something like this in my page title

```
My Blog - Foo Bar Test 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a function for this - static string assignment won't work. The `afterEach` global route hook will help you:

```js
{
    path: '/test/blog/:slug',
    name: 'Surah',
    component: Surah,
    meta: { title: 'My Blog - '}
}

router.afterEach((to, from) =>
{
  document.title = to.meta.title ? to.meta.title + to.params.slug : 'My Default title';
});
```

Comment: its working but the problem is my other page title is undefined,
im using this to call meta title : 
watch: {
    $route(to) {
       document.title = `${to.meta.title} - Golongan Kanan`;
       const link = document.querySelector("[rel='icon']")
       link.setAttribute('href',to.meta.icon)
    }
  },

Comment: I have updated the code to use a default title when the route does not define its own title.

Comment: Thanks mate, you save my day